# want to convert a file in linux (utf-8 default) which is generated in windows (base64)

Tags: java, linux, utf-8

I am displaying a file  in linux (utf-8 default) which is generated in windows (base64). how to make default format in linux to base64 currently it is utf-8. your help is much appreciated thank you.

Comment: I bet the file is CP-1252 encoded? Base64 is no character-encoding like UTF-8. Can you show the code you have now? I bet you're looking for something to read a document and specify it's encoding: Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "windows-1252");

Comment: Use [base64(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/base64) to convert files to and from a base64 encoding. Use [iconv(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv) to convert files between different character sets if needed. (Base64 is a standard way to encode arbitrary data into ASCII text and back, but is not a character set itself like UTF-8 or ASCII are).

Comment: Sorry I am very new to this concept of encoding. I came to know that Base64 is used for encrypting (like cipher) not character encoding like UTF-8 or CP-1252.  So my requirement is to show the same characters in Linux just as we show in windows. basically some weird characters are being printed on image when I execute test case from linux selenium I am unable to copy them I wish i could include a pic attachment here. when I am running the same exact on windows it is clearly giving the sign in page.

Comment: There is no text but encoded text. Encoded text is mostly viewed as bytes. Base64 allows one to treat such bytes again as text because text is more convenient in some circumstances. It's reversible back to bytes. So, even with the use of Base64, you still need to decode with the original character encoding. An author can chose whichever one among [dozens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding#Common_character_encodings) they want. You have to know so they should be telling you in some way. Are they? Perhaps through the Content-Type response header if transferred via HTTP?